# How can i create snowflake table with partitions by hash and parameters

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hana

I have a SAP HANA table with partitions created by HASH like below:

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "header_table" (
    "details" DECIMAL(19,0) CS_FIXED,
     "header" DECIMAL(19,0) CS_FIXED
) UNLOAD PRIORITY 5 AUTO MERGE 
PARTITION BY HASH ("header") 
PARTITIONS 4 WITH PARAMETERS 
    ('PARTNAMES'=(
    '96',
    '93',
    '94',
    '97'));
```

This SAP table is huge ~1bn records.

How can i create a table while using partitions in snowflake like above.

I have looked at the snowflake documentation, but couldn't find the appropriate examples for partitions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you need to partition a table in Snowflake? What's the approximate size (volume not record count) of this table in Snowflake?

Comment: The record count is near to 1bn . Hence the partitioning is needed.

Comment: The fact that the table has that many records in Snowflake doesn't necessarily mean it needs to be partitioned (this is called clustering in Snowflake terminology). Have you loaded the data into Snowflake and run example queries against it? Was the performance less that expected and, having looked at the query profiles, have you determined that the solution to increasing performance is clustering - rather than any other performance improvement technique? SAP and Snowflake work very differently -  Snowflake allows you to cluster a table after it has been created and loaded with data

Comment: i am yet to create a table and load the data. As the source table has partitions already, it will be a best practice to add the partitions on target as well

Comment: Why do you think this would be best practice on Snowflake? As I said in a previous comment, SAP and Snowflake are very different DBMSs and there is no reason to assume that best practice on one would be relevant, or even possible, on the other

Comment: A better answer, is snowflake does not support partitions, and partitions are there to solve three primary problems. 1) file/table size on disk system (not a problem) 2) unloading "old data" for performance reasons (use time filter to prune these zero problem) 3) optimize not reading things known to not be needed, see pruning.